# Why there is an extra index when using apply in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, apply

When I use `apply` to a user defined function in Pandas, it looks like python is creating an additional array. How could I get rid of it? Here is my code:

```
def fnc(group):
    x = group.C.values
    out = x[np.where(x < 0)]
    return pd.DataFrame(out)

data = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.randint(1, 3, 10),
                     'B':3,
                     'C':np.random.normal(0, 1, 10)})

data.groupby(by=['A', 'B']).apply(fnc).reset_index()
```

There is this weird `Level_2` index created. Is there a way to avoid creating it when running my function?

```
    A   B   level_2   0
0   1   3   0        -1.054134802
1   1   3   1        -0.691996447
2   2   3   0        -1.068693768
3   2   3   1        -0.080342046
4   2   3   2        -0.181869799
```

Comment: Are you after: `data[data.C < 0]`?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish. It isn't obvious, and why are you returning a DataFrame in `fnc`?

Comment: What is your expcted result and why are you doing a groupby first and foremost?

Comment: looks like simple `data[data['C'] < 0]` should work fine for you

Comment: My question is why there is a column 'Level_2' created? Is there a way not creating it. @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: not level_2 when running this code here

Comment: I see this level_2 when I use customized functions all the time. @B.M

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As such, you will have no way to avoid level_2 appearing. This is because the result of your grouping is a dataframe with several items in it: pandas is cool enough to understand your wish is to broadcast these items across the grouped keys, yet it is taking the index of the dataframe as an additional level to guarantee coherent output data. So dropping level=-1 at the end of your processing explicitly is expected.

If you want to avoid to reset that extra index, but still have some post processing, another way would be to call transform instead of apply, and get the returned data from `fnc` being the entire group vector where you put `np.nan` for results to exclude. Then, your dataframe will not have an extra level, but you'll need to call `dropna()` afterwards.